# LINQ to SQL C# COALESCE

Tags: sql, linq, coalesce

Given the following table:

```
Length | Width | Color | ID
===========================
    18 |    18 |  blue |  1
---------------------------
    12 |    12 |   red |  1
---------------------------
```

I want to produce a single column/row:

```
 SIZES
 =================
 18 x 18, 12 x 12,
```

I can do this in SQL as follows:

```
DECLARE @SIZES VARCHAR(8000)
SELECT @SIZES = COALESCE(@SIZES, '') + Convert(varchar(80), [Length]) + ' x ' + 
                Convert(varchar(80), [Width]) + ', '
FROM table
where ID = 1
GROUP BY [Length], [Width]
ORDER BY [Length], [Width]
SELECT SIZES = @SIZES
```

But I cannot figure out how to do this in LINQ.

The closest I got was:

```
from t in table
where id == 1
group t by new {
                 t.Length,
                 t.Width
               } into g
orderby g.Key.Length, g.Key.Width
select new {
             SIZES = (Convert.ToInt32(g.Key.Length) + " x " +
                      Convert.ToInt32(g.Key.Width) + ", ")
           }
```

Which produces one column and two rows:

```
SIZES
========
18 x 18,
12 X 12,
```

The converts are unimportant to the problem.  The columns are defined as floats though all are integers.  The key is the COALESCE function I cannot figure out how to do that in LINQ.

Comment: As the others pointed out, LINQ and T-SQL aren't identical in terms of functionality, but I have a question for your SQL:  Why the coalesce?  Why not just do "SET @SIZES = ''" prior to the select statement, opposed to coalescing over every single row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think LINQ to SQL supports this T-SQL trick. The COALESCE isn't really the issue (as Mehrdad points out the equivalent in C# is ??) -- it's the fact that SQL Server aggregates each result via string concatenation into the variable @SIZES. AFAIK LINQ to SQL can't construct this type of query.

This will yield your desired result, but the string concatenation is performed on your side, not on the SQL server side. That probably doesn't matter.

```
var query = 
    from t in table
    where id == 1
    group t by new {
                 t.Length,
                 t.Width
               } into g
    orderby g.Key.Length, g.Key.Width
    select new {
             SIZES = (Convert.ToInt32(g.Key.Length) + " x " +
                      Convert.ToInt32(g.Key.Width) + ", ")
           };

var result = string.Join(string.Empty, query.Select(r => r.SIZES).ToArray());
```

Answer (score 10):

Try `??` ([null coalesce operator](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/09/20/the-new-c-null-coalescing-operator-and-using-it-with-linq.aspx)) like:

```
t.Length ?? 0
```

Comment: Using LINQ to SQL this generates COALESCE in the resulting T-SQL

Comment: On EF 6 this actually becomes a `CASE` statement.

Answer (score 0):

I would just return the `int` sizes from SQL and do the string building client-side:

```
var query = 
    from t in table
    where id == 1
    group t by new {
                 t.Length,
                 t.Width
               } into g
    orderby g.Key.Length, g.Key.Width
    select g.Key;

var sizeStrings = from s in query.AsEnumerable()
                  select string.Format("{0} x {1}", s.Length, s.Width);

var result = string.Join(", ", sizeStrings.ToArray());
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the .Aggregate function, like so:

```
(from t in table
where id == 1
group t by new {
             t.Length,
             t.Width
           } into g
orderby g.Key.Length, g.Key.Width
select new {
         SIZES = (Convert.ToInt32(g.Key.Length) + " x " +
                  Convert.ToInt32(g.Key.Width) + ", ")
       }).Aggregate((x,y) => x + y)
```

This should kick out a single string, like you want.
Aggregate just internally maintains the exact same variable you had defined in the SQL, just implicitly.