# C# equivalent of COALESCE () in SQL

Tags: c#, datatable

I have a DataTable dtTemp as follows

```
---------------------------------
   ID      |   Name
---------------------------------
  101      |   ABC
  102      |   PQR
---------------------------------
```

I just want a `string which consist of all names`. 
Like

> ```
> String str="ABC,PQR"
> ```

Comment: [Click here][1] hope this will help you. 

also [see][2]

Thanks


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/403445/is-there-a-vb-net-equivalent-for-cs-operator
  [2]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1245526/linq-to-sql-c-sharp-coalesce

Comment: wait, but that's not what `COALESCE()` does at all ?! http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use LINQ:

```
String.Join(",", table.AsEnumerable().Select(r => r.Name));
```

(or `r["Name"]` if it's not a typed dataset)