# How to implement large COALESCE in LINQ-to-SQL query

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq, t-sql, linq-to-sql

If I have a lot of columns to COALESCE in a TSQL query that needs to be executed as a LINQ-to-SQL query. How can it be converted to an efficient LINQ-to-SQL query? For example:

```
SELECT COALESCE(t1.Date, t2.DocDate, t3.PostingDate, t4.DocDate, t5.DocDate) DocDate
FROM t0
LEFT JOIN t1 ON t0.t1id = t1.id
LEFT JOIN t2 ON t0.t2id = t2.id
LEFT JOIN t3 ON t0.t3id = t3.id
LEFT JOIN t4 ON t0.t4id = t4.id
LEFT JOIN t5 ON t0.t5id = t5.id
```

Is there any way to write this in a LINQ query better than the following?

```
Dim result = ( _
   From c in context.t0 _
   Select DocDate=If(t0.t1.Date, If(t0.t2.DocDate, If(t0.t3.PostingDate, _
   If(t0.t4.DocDate, t0.t5.DocDate)))))
```

I actually have a couple dozen columns within the coalesce to "merge", and two different coalesces to return two different coalesced columns, so the result could get pretty messy, and I fear it'd be pretty inefficient if it weren't processed as COALESCE.

Comment: Would it be out of the question to use a stored procedure for that? You can call a SP through LINQ: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386975%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: We are writing an AddOn to an SAP product, and SAP policy prohibits stored procedures in their database. However I could call context.Execute on the SQL if there's no better way.

Comment: So using the TSQL is not an option?

Comment: Only to the extent that it works from within DataContext.ExecuteQuery (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.executequery(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: This related question might be helpful:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1245526/linq-to-sql-c-sharp-coalesce

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't an exact solution, but if you could switch to C#, your code would look more like:

```
result = From c in context.t0 
    Select DocDate = t0.t1.Date ?? t0.t2.DocDate ?? t0.t3.PostingDate ?? t0.t4.DocDate ?? t0.t5.DocDate;
```

I made the jump from VB to C# a few months ago and haven't looked back.

Comment: I think the real concern is about performance. Do either of our solutions get built into an SQL COALESCE statement?

Comment: I haven't tried it, but a google search revealed that both approaches should get turned into SQL COALESCE.  What you posted is the same as what I posted, just in VB.